# can an Ipad with only a Lightning to USB cable be used to control a lasermaster 2. Lightburn software is hoped to be used

Tags: usb, ipad, lightning

I've purchased a LaserMaster2 engraver. I would like to use a current Ipad to run LightBurn software to control it. The Ipad only has a Lightning port and I have the Lightning  to USB cable I use to charge the Ipad. would that work ? Assuming all drivers are correct and the control board is functional.

Comment: If you already have all the relevant parts: have you tried? What was the result? What do the manuals for the engraver and the software say?

Comment: There is no iOS version of LightBurn, so.. no.